# How does Django construct the url returned by FileSystemStorage?

Tags: django, storage

I have model, for testing purposes with just an ImageField. This ImageField is bound to a FileSystemStorage like the following:

```
fs_test = FileSystemStorage(location = settings.FS_TEST_FILES,
                            base_url = settings.FS_TEST_URL)

class TestModel(models.Model):
  image = models.ImageField(storage=fs_test,upload_to='image')
```

the settings look like this:

```
FS_TEST_FILES = os.path.normpath(MEDIA_ROOT+'/fs_test')
FS_TEST_URL = os.path.normpath(MEDIA_URL+'/fs_test/')
```

When uploading, the file is uploaded to "media/root/fs_test/image/filename.png". No worry until here. But when calling "image.url", i get "media/url/image/filename.png". Shouldn't that be base_url+filename, which in this case would be "media/url/fs-test/image/filename.png"? Why not?

**edit:**
some more information on this. Djangos FileField class defines the url access as follows:

```
def _get_url(self):
    self._require_file()
    return self.storage.url(self.name)
url = property(_get_url)
```

and the Storage class defines:

```
def url(self, name):
    if self.base_url is None:
        raise ValueError("This file is not accessible via a URL.")
    return urlparse.urljoin(self.base_url, name).replace('\\', '/')
```

but my code returns the standard MEDIA_URL, not the base_url defined in fs_test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out your leading and trailing slashes... use urlparse instead of os

```
FS_TEST_URL = urlparse.urljoin(MEDIA_URL,'fs_test/')
```